# Extract one row for same key based on a column value oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a result set in oracle that looks somehow like below with 3 columns: account, client and address:

| Account. | Client. | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abc. | Aaa. | Mailing |
| Abc | Aaa. | Domicile |
| Ccc. | Aaa. | Mailing |
| Ccc. | Aaa. | Domicile |
| Ccc. | Aaa. | Office |
| Ddd. | Bbb. | Domicile |
| Ddd. | Bbb. | Office |

In case I have a key pair client/account that has multiples address declared I need to get only the mailing one and in case I don’t have a mailing address declared I need to take only the domicile one.
These should be the results:

| Account. | Client. | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abc. | Aaa. | Mailing |
| Ccc. | Aaa. | Mailing |
| Ccc. | Aaa. | Mailing |
| Ddd. | Bbb. | Domicile |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the first row for each account and use a `CASE` expression to set the priority:

```sql
SELECT account, client, address
FROM   (
  SELECT account, client, address,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY account
           ORDER BY CASE address
                    WHEN 'mailing'  THEN 1
                    WHEN 'domicile' THEN 2
                                    ELSE 3
                    END
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```